# Flutter pass BuildContext in Widget callback

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter widget like this:

```
Widget build(context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => Future.value(false),
      child: FlutterLogin(
        title: "Hubble",
        onSignup: _signUpUser,
```

The function `_signUpUser` takes only one argument of type `LoginData`, but I need to access the `BuildContext context` in this function. How can I achieve this? Passing the context gives me an error saying too many positional arguments.

Comment: Please show more code to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like

```
FlutterLogin(
    title: "Hubble",
    onSignup: (data) => _signupUser(data, context)
...
```

where _signupUser takes 2 arguments, the first being your `LoginData` and the last being the BuildContext.